# Apply gradient to stack panel Background color/Images in silverlight

Tags: silverlight, gradient

If I use  in a stack panel I can only give color background to stack panel using LinearGradient but can't add other element on it.

Any Idea how can I do this?

Thanx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably the easiest best way to apply a gradient to a StackPanel is to contain it within a Border:

```
<Border>
  <Border.Background>
    ... you gradient goes here ...
  </Border.Background>

  <StackPanel>
    .. your content goes here ...
  </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: Why would you not apply the gradient directly to the Stackpanel?

Answer (score 3):

Not sure how you manage to get that to fail.  There is a super simple (ableit ugly gradient).  Works fine:-

```
    <StackPanel>
        <StackPanel.Background>
            <LinearGradientBrush EndPoint="1,0.5" StartPoint="0,0.5">
                <GradientStop Color="Black" Offset="0" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FFC95AFF" Offset="0.484" />
                <GradientStop Color="#FF3E5E7F" Offset="0.242" />
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </StackPanel.Background>
        <TextBlock Foreground="White" Text="Hello World" />
    </StackPanel>
```